# Corrupted stack while using MapWindowPoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stack

Got `Stack around the variable "rc" was corrupted` error, when trying to test this code (uses returned coord to move mouse there)
Please see the code below:

```
int TestPluginAPI::getmidX()
{
//RECT rect; 
HWND hWnd;
hWnd = getBrowserHwnd();
RECT rc;
if(GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc))  // get client coords 
{
MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.left), 2); // convert top-left x
MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.right), 2); // convert bottom-right x
MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.top), 2); // convert top-left y
MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.bottom), 2); // convert bottom-right y
return rc.left;
}
else {return 0;}
}
```

Can you tell me, what's wrong?

Comment: Worth to read documentation of these functions before you use them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your stack gets corrupted when you pass &rc.bottom and say there are two points.  There's only one.  Buy Microsoft a cigar for keeping you out of deep, deep trouble.

Comment: Just in sake of curiosity, what kind of terrible trouble do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should be just this

```
if(GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc))  // get client coords 
{
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc), 2);
    return rc.left;
}
```

A rectangle is two points (top left and bottom right). So you only need to call MapWindowPoints once, with a count of 2.

Comment: It.. makes sense, will test it riiiiight now